# update records in a union select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've two tables with events that I want to union and sort by date and I need a value in the result that I can group the records by for reporting - in this case `code2`

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl1 (code1 INT, codeDate DATETIME, code2 INT)
CREATE TABLE #tbl2 (code1 INT, codeDate DATETIME, code2 INT )

INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES( 1, '01 jan 2013 12:00:00', 123)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES( 2, '01 jan 2013 14:00:00', 123)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES( 1, '01 jan 2013 15:00:00', 234)
INSERT INTO #tbl1 VALUES( 2, '01 jan 2013 18:00:00', 234)

INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES( 10, '01 jan 2013 12:10:00', 0)
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES( 20, '01 jan 2013 13:20:00', 0)
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES( 10, '01 jan 2013 15:10:00', 0)
INSERT INTO #tbl2 VALUES( 20, '01 jan 2013 16:20:00', 0)

SELECT * FROM #tbl1 UNION SELECT * FROM  #tbl2  ORDER BY CODEDATE
```

Returns

```
code1   codeDate                    code2
1       2013-01-01 12:00:00.000     123
10      2013-01-01 12:10:00.000     0
20      2013-01-01 13:20:00.000     0
2       2013-01-01 14:00:00.000     123
1       2013-01-01 15:00:00.000     234
10      2013-01-01 15:10:00.000     0
20      2013-01-01 16:20:00.000     0
2       2013-01-01 18:00:00.000     234
```

Id like to get the values in the `code2` column to be updated so the tbl2 records that fall between the date values in tbl1 have the `code2` value from tbl1. (rows 2,3,6 & 7 in results)  eg:

```
code1   codeDate                    code2
1       2013-01-01 12:00:00.000     123
10      2013-01-01 12:10:00.000     123
20      2013-01-01 13:20:00.000     123
2       2013-01-01 14:00:00.000     123
1       2013-01-01 15:00:00.000     234
10      2013-01-01 15:10:00.000     234
20      2013-01-01 16:20:00.000     234
2       2013-01-01 18:00:00.000     234
```

Is this possible with a `UNION` or do i need a different approach?

Comment: Please add the database you are using is asking sql questions, there are alot of diffrences between oracle/postgess/mysql/mssql ...

Comment: Tagging as MS SQL Server based on the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
update #tbl2
set code2 = t1.code
from
    #tbl2 t2
        inner join
    (

        select 
            t1s.codeDate start,
            t1f.codeDate finish,
            t1s.code2 code
         from #tbl1 t1s 
            inner join #tbl1 t1f 
                on t1s.code2 = t1f.code2
        where t1s.code1=1
        and t1f.code1 = 2
    ) t1
        on t2.codeDate between t1.start and t1.finish

 SELECT * FROM #tbl1 UNION SELECT * FROM  #tbl2  ORDER BY CODEDATE
```

But really, your data structure needs sorting out (which is what the bulk of the above query attempts to do)

Comment: It seems like it should work, but it's not giving the required results in sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e554/18). [Had to remove the hashes because it was throwing some error]

Comment: @Raze2dust Works for me in the fiddle!

Comment: @podiluska Thanks, works for me. Agree the data structure needs sorting out to make this easier too.